# AWS Elastic Beanstalk not resolving secret from Secrets Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, aws-secrets-manager

I'm following the instructions from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/single-container-docker-configuration.html#docker-configuration.remote-repo to inject secrets from Secrets Manager (section "Using AWS Secrets Manager")

I'm using the Docker platform on Elastic Beanstalk `arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:ap-southeast-2::platform/Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.6.1`

I have the following secret blob in Secrets Manager called "AppSecret"

```json
{ "username": "Bruce.Wayne", "password": "I_AM_BATMAN" }
```

In `.ebextensions/options.config` I have the following

```yaml
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    USER: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:AppSecret:SecretString:username}}'
    PASSWORD: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:AppSecret:SecretString:password}}'
```

I also have a `.platform/hooks/postdeploy/dump.sh` (for testing) which contains

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

echo "PASSWORD $(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment -k PASSWORD)"
```

The IAM Role (`aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role`) has the `SecretsManagerReadWrite` policy attached which has the IAM Action `"secretsmanager:*"`. This should cover the requirement (from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html#dynamic-references-secretsmanager)

> To specify a secret stored in Secrets Manager, you must have access to call GetSecretValue for the secret.

The problem is that when the ZIP is deployed to Elastic Beanstalk, the secret is not being resolved. The output from the logs `eb-hooks.log` is

```
PASSWORD {{resolve:secretsmanager:AppSecret:SecretString:password}}
```

The same `options.config` has SSM references resolved correctly, it's only `secretsmanager` that is failing.

It's probably some obscure part of Cloud Formation, or something simple I've overlooked but I have no idea why this is failing.

(Alternatively if someone could point me towards how to use SSM SecureString's with Elastic Beanstalk that would be much better)

Comment: Hi @kierans did you find a solution to this in the meantime? I also find it very odd that I followed the documentation strictly and it is not working out.

Comment: Not sure if this SSM documentation is relevent.
[ssm secure strings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html#dynamic-references-ssm-secure-strings)

Answer (score 0):

recently I faced the same challenge how to pass credentials in my app. It's true Elastic Beanstalk not resolving secrets. There are a few ways how to do it. I gonna share one that works for me.

Prerequisite
your IAM role in Elastic Beanstalk should be able to retrieve secrets.
Below I gonna provide you CloudFormation stack where I added to my Elastic Beanstalk IAM role and grant it to retrieve secrets from the AWS Secret Manager with name of the secret **name/ofyoursecret/db**

```
EBInstanceRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: 'ec2.amazonaws.com'
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: '/'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier'
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: 'AdditionalPermissions'
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: 'secretsmanager:GetSecretValue'
                Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:name/ofyoursecret/db*'
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: 'ecr:GetAuthorizationToken'
                Resource: "*"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: 
                  - 'ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability'
                  - 'ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer'
                  - 'ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy'
                  - 'ecr:DescribeRepositories'
                  - 'ecr:ListImages'
                  - 'ecr:DescribeImages'
                  - 'ecr:BatchGetImage'
                Resource:
                  - !Sub 'arn:aws:ecr:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:repository/name-repository*'


  EBInstanceProfile:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile'
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
        - !Ref EBInstanceRole
        
  ElasticBeanstalkApplication:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application'
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref Project

  ElasticBeanstalkEnvironment:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment'
    Properties:
      EnvironmentName: !Sub '${Project}-${Environment}'
      ApplicationName: !Ref ElasticBeanstalkApplication
      SolutionStackName: '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.7.1 running Docker'
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment'
          OptionName: 'HOST_URL'
          Value: !ImportValue 
            'Fn::Sub': "${Environment}-${Project}-DBEndpoint"
        - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment'
          OptionName: 'DATABASE_SECRET_ARN'
          Value: !Sub 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:name/ofyoursecret/db'
```

Now I gonna use the sh script to retrieve secrets from the AWS Secret Manager. Because I passed in the env variables DATABASE_SECRET_ARN it's the ARN of my secret (Amazon Resource Names (ARNs) are not secrets)
And I passed here database HOST URL.

get_credentials.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

# Get the AWS region from EC2 instance metadata
AWS_REGION=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone | sed 's/[a-zA-Z]$//')

# Check if AWS_REGION is obtained successfully
if [ -z "$AWS_REGION" ]; then
    echo "Failed to get AWS region from EC2 metadata."
    exit 1
fi

# Get DATABASE_SECRET_ARN and HOST_URL from environment variables
DATABASE_SECRET_ARN=$(printenv DATABASE_SECRET_ARN)
HOST_URL=$(printenv HOST_URL)

if [ -z "$DATABASE_SECRET_ARN" ]; then
    echo "DATABASE_SECRET_ARN environment variable not found."
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$HOST_URL" ]; then
    echo "HOST_URL environment variable not found."
    exit 1
fi

# Use AWS CLI to get the secret value
SECRET_STRING=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id $DATABASE_SECRET_ARN --region $AWS_REGION --query SecretString --output text)

# Check if SECRET_STRING is obtained successfully
if [ -z "$SECRET_STRING" ]; then
    echo "Failed to retrieve secret string from Secrets Manager."
    exit 1
fi

# Extract credentials from SECRET_STRING
USERNAME=$(echo $SECRET_STRING | jq -r .username)
DBPASSWORD=$(echo $SECRET_STRING | jq -r .dbpassword)
DBNAME=$(echo $SECRET_STRING | jq -r .dbname)

# Optionally, export DATABASE_URL to be available to other processes started by this script
export DATABASE_URL="postgresql+asyncpg://${USERNAME}:${DBPASSWORD}@${HOST_URL}:5432/${DBNAME}"
```

In my Dockerfile I use entry point script and pass my value in the .env file

**entrypoint.sh**

```
   #!/bin/sh

echo "Starting the entrypoint script at $(date)"
echo "Sourcing get_cred_db.sh to set environment variables..."
. ./get_credentials.sh

# Assuming get_cred_db.sh successfully sets and exports DATABASE_URL
# Now, write DATABASE_URL and potentially other environment variables to a .env file
echo "DATABASE_URL=$DATABASE_URL" > /usr/src/app/.env


echo "Environment variables recorded in .env file."

# Execute the passed command
exec "$@"
```